# Future perfect or Future perfect continuous in the following sentence?

Tags: tenses, future, future-perfect

I am not sure why this sentence is incorrect from tense's perspective.

> It is certain that the construction of the road will be completed by the winter of 2014.

Also, according to my book its incorrect. According to my book, the sentence should have taken the future perfect form as emphasis is on completion. But they are re-writing the sentence as:

> It is certain that the construction of the road will have been completed by the winter of 2014.

But this sentence takes future perfect continuous form. So I think it should be **will have completed by the winter of 2014.** Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "will have been completed" is Future Perfect Passive.

Comment: Anything completed by the 10th of May will have certainly been completed by the 11th. And I'd just refer to the road's being completed.

Comment: What AlexB says: *Complete* is a transitive verb: the construction doesn't "complete" itself, it must "be completed" by the contractors. And what Edwin Ashworth says, too; your book is rather more picky than is called for. (But do what your book says anyway, so you pass the exam!)

Comment: In the first sentence, *completed* is an adjective. The version of this in the present tense is **the road is completed.** Here, we have the verb **is** and the adjective complement **completed**. Putting this in the future, we get **the road will be completed,** a perfectly grammatical sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor  That's how I'd parse it, too; but if I wanted an adjective I'd use *complete* and not entangle myself in such ambiguities.

Comment: @PeterShor. In this clause I wouldn't say that _completed_ was an adjective, but the past participle of *complete*. It forms part of the verb phrase _will be completed_.

Comment: @PeterShor  Quite; but I would in "the road will be complete". I admit, however, that my ear in this is probably old-fashioned, and I would go out of my way to avoid employing a passive participle here, precisely because the natural parsing is as a passive construction.

Comment: @Barrie: quite right. I don't know why I was thinking it had to be an adjective there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is fine. *Will* + *be* + past participle is a passive construction, and  expresses a future state, act or condition. The substitution of *have been* for *be* is also possible, but it gives a slightly different perspective on the timing.

There is no continuous form in either sentence, and your proposed version *will have completed* is not really grammatical in this context.

Comment: @Baarrie England: According to my understanding the first sentence sounds okay to me. But according to my book the sentence talks about the completion of an action before a given time, so the future simple tense is inappropriate (the first sentence is in simple future tense) so they are recommending on future perfect.

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: Its local book. You might be not knowing.

Comment: Well, it’s wrong, or at least misleading.

Comment: But I am not getting why future perfect is incorrect. As it also shows that the roads will be completed before 2014.

Comment: It isn't incorrect.

Comment: @Sudhir  In certain contexts future perfect *may* be incorrect, or ungraceful, and your book is probably teaching you a form which will still be correct in those contexts. Teachers, and the writers of style guides, will often give you oversimplified rules which prevent you from making errors.